# What campaigns did the Mexican army fight against American Indians in the North?

Tags: war, mexico

I am seeking information about Mexican Army Operations against Apaches and other Native American militant tribes (such as the Apaches, Comanches, Yaquis, etc)  in the northern part of the country. If anyone can go into details of  this aspect of the North American Indian wars, please share. The only current source that I  know of is Geronimo's autobiography, which describes battles with the Mexican Army that seem to be on the same scale of some of the battles that happened on the Northern Plains. There must be documentation of these campaigns (in Spanish) in Mexican military references.

Comment: T.R.  Fehrenbach has a history of Mexico titled "Fire and Blood" which may have some of the background you seek, but it's not by itself a primary source.  The original edition covered Mexico up until about 1940, though IIRC subsequent editions go as far as more contemporary issues as the long standing success of the PRI.

Comment: Do you mean in the north of what is now Mexico,  or do you mean north as in the territories that are now part of the United States.    Also any chance you have read Blood Meridian,  it is fiction but a very well written book about that time period and issues.

Answer (score 7):

David Weber in *The Mexican Frontier* (1982) suggested that the best English-language source on the Mexican conflict with northern tribes is a 1963-1972 series of articles by Ralph A. Smith in the journals Hispanic American Historical Review, Arizona and the West, and Arizoniana. For a Spanish-language source Weber liked Carlos J. Sierra's book *Los indios de la frontera* (1980).